# Unable to connect to Elasticsearch client running locally: receiving 'connection refused'

Tags: android, kotlin, elasticsearch

I am experiencing connection issues with my Elasticsearch client running locally. Specifically, when I try to connect using localhost in the RestClient.builder, I receive a java.net.connectException: connection refused error, and when I try to use my IP address, I get a timeout error. I have developed two different versions of my test app, one using a low-level REST client and the other using the Java API, both of which were developed using Kotlin for and android application. Despite this, I still receive the same errors. I have included the code for both versions below. Can anyone suggest a solution or help me diagnose the issue?

Here are a code snipet to better understand my situation. Code used in the low level rest client:

```
private fun sendFileStandard() {
        val restClient = RestClient.builder(
            HttpHost("192.167.208.131", 9200, "http"),
            HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http")
        ).build()

        val request = Request(
            "GET",
            "/"
        )

        var risultato = "defualt value"

        doAsync {
            val cancellable: Cancellable = restClient.performRequestAsync(request,
                object : ResponseListener {
                    override fun onSuccess(response: Response) {
                        dii("onsuccess", response)
                        risultato = "success" +response.toString()
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(exception: Exception) {
                        dii("onfailure", exception)
                        risultato = "exception" + exception.toString()
                    }
                })
        }
        dii("risultato", risultato)

        Thread.sleep(9000)
        restClient.close();

    }
```

the java api ones:

```
val restClient = RestClient.builder(
            HttpHost("localhost", 9200)
        ).build()

        val transport: ElasticsearchTransport = RestClientTransport(
            restClient, JacksonJsonpMapper()
        )
        val client = ElasticsearchClient(transport)

        val input: Reader = StringReader(
            "{'@timestamp': '2022-04-08T13:55:32Z', 'level': 'warn', 'message': 'Some log message'}"
                .replace('\'', '"')
        )

        val request = IndexRequest.of { i: IndexRequest.Builder<JsonData?> ->
            i
                .index("logs")
                .withJson(input)
        }
        doAsync {
            val response: IndexResponse = client.index(request)
        }
```

Comment: Can you try `curl localhost:9200` also try with HTTPS also try with -u elastic :)

Comment: I've tried using HTTPS and i get the same result. I don't get how can I use a curl or -u elastic in an android application

Comment: @MusabDogan you curl comment made me realize that i still have the "xpack.security.enabled" property to "true" . I set it to false but the problem persist

Comment: if you checked the HTTP and HTTPS the problem can be because of the IP address. Whether Elasticsearch is not running or there is a network problem between the application and elasticsearch.

Comment: @MusabDogan this problem happen also if i try to execute it on localnetwork so i don't really know what kind of network problem could it be

Comment: You need to make sure your elasticsearch up and running on localhost and port 9200

Comment: @MusabDogan it respond to the curl localhost:9200 so i suppose is running on this port plus I checked it out the and that line is commented so as far as I know elasticsearch should use the default port that is 9200. Even when i write localhost:9200 on my browser bar it work

Comment: that's correct localhost and 9200 is default

Comment: maybe if you can update elasticsearch.yml http.host from localhost to 0.0.0.0 it can route the traffic to elasticsearch, restart the elasticsearch after update

Comment: @MusabDogan I've kept the http.host at default value that is 0.0.0.0, change it to 192.168.0.1 cause elasticsearch error when starting up. I tried to change network.host to 0.0.0.0 and i get the same result